# Maven dependecies for Mojarra 2.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, jsf-2

I want to use `Mojarra 2.1`

http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html

and my container is `Tomcat 7` and I am using `IceFaces 2`.

Should I include the API only as follows?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE:** I am using servlet 3.0.1, jsp 2.2.1, el 2.2 maybe it's conflicting:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use Mojarra 2.1.2 with this dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @Mika It's not mandatory, it should be automatically set to compile.

Comment: i got following exception after that change: `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/FacesException`

Comment: do you have any ideas why to get such exception ?

Comment: You may want to track this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807549/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-o Someone else is today also having the same problem with Maven and classpath pollution.

Comment: You shouldn't have 2 accounts.

Comment: it's my colleague account we are working on same project, sorry :(

Comment: @flash, any help about this issue ?

Comment: @Mika Should work very fine. Well, I don't have a tomcat 7 here. I'm working with tomcat 6.

Comment: @flash do you use EL 2.1 or EL 2.2 with tomcat 6 ?

Comment: Tomcat 6 is bundled with EL 2.1

Comment: I get nearly the same EXception in TestNG: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/lifecycle/Lifecycle.