# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I get the following exception on startup of my JSF web application:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3786)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

This my `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <display-name>J2S</display-name>
 <context-param>
  <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
  <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
  welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

How is this exception caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Make sure the myfaces jar is in the lib folder of your web app. You can download the myfaces library [here](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/myfaces/binaries/myfaces-core-assembly-2.1.7-bin.zip).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener

The `ClassNotFoundException` means that the mentioned class is missing in the application's runtime classpath. The mentioned class is part of [MyFaces](https://myfaces.apache.org) JSF implementation. This is thus missing in your application's runtime classpath.

In case you're using Maven, this is the proper [coordinate](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-impl) to install MyFaces 2.3:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
    <version><!-- Check https://myfaces.apache.org --></version>
</dependency>
```

Check https://myfaces.apache.org or the [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-impl) for the exact version number of the latest available 2.3.x. Currently (Aug 2023) that is `2.3.10`.

In case you're manually carrying around loose JAR files, then you need to [download](https://myfaces.apache.org/#/core23?id=downloads) the myfaces-core-assembly-x.y.z-bin.zip file, unpack it and put the JAR files found in the `/lib` folder in the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp project. Note that MyFaces ships with three `myfaces-*.jar` files, you should put *either* both the `myfaces-api` and `myfaces-impl` JAR files, *or* alone the `myfaces-bundle` JAR file in the `/WEB-INF/lib` and thus not all three.

#### See also:

- [How to properly install and configure JSF libraries via Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081234/how-to-properly-install-and-configure-jsf-libraries-via-maven)

Comment: Thanks the error dispear when i adding myfaces-api and myfaces-impl but i got anther error

Comment: SEVERE: An error occured while initializing MyFaces: javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory

Comment: Please press `Ask Question` button whenever you have a new question.

Comment: SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
javax.faces.FacesException: org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationFactoryImpl

Comment: Please press `Ask Question` button whenever you have a new question. You should not post new questions in comments of an already answered question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using Tomcat7 on Eclipse. I had all the required jar files.  I discoverd that it was due to a wrong configuration of the server. Be sure, while creating a dynamic web project on Eclipse, to choose for Tomcat the JSF configuration, not the default one.

Comment: I also have problem with the Tomcat. I did not quite understand what do I need to do, could you clarify with more details please?