# Spring web-flow with JSF ClassNotFoundException issue

Tags: maven, jsf-2, spring-webflow

I am working on a project using Spring Webflow and JSF. I am trying to accomplish something similar to the booking-faces example of Spring Webflow https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-webflow-samples/tree/master/booking-faces. I get the following error while trying to execute a web-flow.

```
org/apache/myfaces/renderkit/StateCacheUtils

viewId=/WEB-INF/flows/main/enterSearchCriteria.xhtml
location=C:\Users\workspace4\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core  \tmp1\wtpwebapps\myWebApp\WEB-INF\flows\main\enterSearchCriteria.xhtml
phaseId=RENDER_RESPONSE(6)

Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.StateCacheUtils
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
```

The full stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/myfaces/renderkit/StateCacheUtils
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.MyFacesFlowResponseStateManager.getWrappedMyfacesResponseStateManager(MyFacesFlowResponseStateManager.java:66)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.MyFacesFlowResponseStateManager.isWriteStateAfterRenderViewRequired(MyFacesFlowResponseStateManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.setWritingState(ViewHandlerImpl.java:371)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.writeState(ViewHandlerImpl.java:315)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.writeState(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:65)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlFormRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlFormRendererBase.java:220)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:665)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:202)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:119)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:56)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:665)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:545)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1981)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
    at org.springframework.faces.support.LifecycleWrapper.render(LifecycleWrapper.java:54)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.render(JsfView.java:87)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:293)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:242)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:220)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.StateCacheUtils
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    ... 86 more
```

I checked the answer from the stackoverflow post: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679490/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-myfaces-webapp-startupservletcontex) . However I am using Maven and don't have a /WEB-INF/lib directory. I have JSF dependencies on my classpath through Maven dependencies. Not sure, what's going on. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyFaces repackaged StateCacheUtils in version 2.1.10. So spring-webflow will not work with myfaces 2.1.10 or higher.

I created an [issue in jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWF-1638) for this. Maybe it will be fixed in a further version.

Meanwhile there is a very very **VERY** ugly workaround for this problem:

Create a class org.apache.myfaces.rederkit.StateCacheUtils in your own project and let it inherit from the new location unsing the following code:

```
package org.apache.myfaces.renderkit;

public class StateCacheUtils extends org.apache.myfaces.application.viewstate.StateCacheUtils {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like StateCacheUtils has moved to a new package as of late last year (2012) and now lives under org.apache.myfaces.application.viewstate. It looks like a dependency issue between Spring Webflow and MyFaces. You might want to raise this on the Spring Weblflow forums.