# Error while deploying jSF 1.1 based application Tomcat 8?

Tags: spring, jsf, java-8, tomcat8, myfaces

in my project I'm using Apache MyFaces 1.1 lib, Spring 3.2.9, Java 8 and tomcat 8.

I'm getting following error while deploying in tomcat

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Persistent Faces Servlet] in context with path [/app_Palisades] threw exception [java.lang.Exception: javax.faces.FacesException: Problem in renderResponse: /YardSnap.xhtml @183,89 timeZone="#{yardSnapBean.timeZone}" null] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:44)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:85)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:183)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.TagAttribute.getObject(TagAttribute.java:233)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.TagAttribute.getObject(TagAttribute.java:166)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ConvertDateTimeHandler.setAttributes(ConvertDateTimeHandler.java:107)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ConvertHandler.apply(ConvertHandler.java:116)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:140)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:65)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:95)
    at com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DFaceletViewHandler.java:274)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderView(D2DViewHandler.java:159)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:146)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:19)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2$1.respond(View.java:48)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ServletRequestResponse.respondWith(ServletRequestResponse.java:201)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2.serve(View.java:77)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:149)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.MultiViewServer.service(MultiViewServer.java:67)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.ServerProxy.service(ServerProxy.java:11)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet$4.service(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:149)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:55)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.my.bizzz.security.ui.filter.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 02, 2016 5:17:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase modified
INFO: One or more JARs have been modified in the web application [/app_MyApplication
Jun 02, 2016 5:17:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
```

Please help me, I'm facing this issue from 2 days.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How and why exactly did you override Apache EL with Oracle EL? If you already have no clue what I'm asking, then start with listing all JARs you have in `/WEB-INF/lib`. The stack trace at least tells that the webapp is using Oracle EL, which is strange as Tomcat itself already ships with Apache EL out the box. This very much suggests classpath pollution with wrong/duplicate/competing libraries supplied via webapp which only conflict server's own libraries, resulting in "weird" exceptions coming from internal classes like this.

Comment: actually this project is a migration from weblogic to tomcat . that why  , I've dependency in POM.XMl             <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
   <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: That's a server-provided dependency which you're supposed to mark as `<scope>provided</scope>`.  This applies to all server-provided dependencies. This is most likely the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081234/how-to-properly-install-and-configure-jsf-libraries-via-maven/8081384#8081384

Comment: so what should I do, remove that dependency or to give <scope>provided</scope> or use some other library . I'm fully confused right now.

Comment: Take a pause and then read the given link once again with a fresh mind and logical thinking capabilities.

Comment: OK . Thanks for replying.. :)

Comment: the above error is gone but some other issue I'm facing seems like database information is not right but it's proper . I'm using Spring-jdbc instead of commons-dbcp .     error I'm getting is                                                                                                                           java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported by BasicDataSource
 at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1551)

Comment: That problem has a different cause. Just copypaste error message into [a search engine](https://google.com/search?q=java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException%3A+Not+supported+by+BasicDataSource+at+org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection) to find clues.