# Why is the forEach tag not working with Tomcat but all is fine with Jetty?

Tags: maven, jsf, tomcat, jetty, jstl

These are the dependencies I have in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

and the Jetty plugin I use:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.1.v20140609</version>
</plugin>
```

and the Tomcat I use is: 8.5.4.

This is the view I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Student List</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <c:forEach items="#{studentBean.studentList}"
               var="student">
        #{student.fullname}
        <br/>
    </c:forEach>
</h:body>
</html>
```

When I run this application like this:

```
mvn clean install
mvn jetty:start
```

and visit localhost:8080, I will see the list just fine on my browser.

```
Koray Tugay 
Mick Jagger
```

Now if I copy the .war file created and deploy it to Tomcat, I will see:

```
type Exception report
message javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$UserComponentHandlerFactory.createHandler(AbstractTagLibrary.java:344)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagStatus
```

(full stack trace [here](http://pastebin.com/wYuKQPu9)..)

Now you maybe tempted to say **Tomcat does not come with JSTL, you should add it in your pom.xml as dependency!** However, at this point I will ask you:

Why does it work fine with Jetty?

Also, when I go through the **jsf-impl-2.2.13.jar**, which maven downloaded, I find the file called: **jstl-core.taglib** under com/sun/faces/metadata/taglib.

And in this file, I see this tag declaration:

```
<tag>
    <description><![CDATA[
            The basic iteration tag, accepting many different
            collection types and supporting subsetting and other
            functionality
        ]]></description>
    <tag-name>forEach</tag-name>
    <handler-class>com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachHandler</handler-class>
    <attribute>
        <description><![CDATA[
                Collection of items to iterate over.
            ]]></description>
        <name>items</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>java.lang.Object</type>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

and also, class **com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachHandler** is already included in the jsf-impl-2.2.13.jar.

So my understanding is, c:forEach is supposed to be included in the JSF implementation. Why is Tomcat not liking this situation?

If I include this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

in pom.xml, for loop will loop happily in Tomcat as well. How does this work, or not work?

Comment: Clean & build / (re)deploy the application all over again from scratch.

Comment: @Tiny It does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class [`com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachHandler`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/jstl/core/ForEachHandler.java#ForEachHandler) has via its dependency [`com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.JstlIterationStatus`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/jstl/core/JstlIterationStatus.java#JstlIterationStatus) a dependency on `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagStatus`.

Tomcat doesn't ship with it. Hence the required JSTL dependency.

Jetty apparently provides its own JSTL library. So you don't need to include it via webapp. You should mark it at least `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: But what I do not understand is, why is it not included in JSF jars? If JSF is including ForEachHandler, it should include the dependencies of it as well no?

Comment: Why should it? If you go on this route, you'd also wonder why it doesn't include Servlet, JSP, CDI, etc or even Java SE dependencies. Those are just the minimum requirements which should already be provided by the environment. It is needless to include all those dependencies in JSF libraries. The `ForeachHandler` is necessary because JSP based tags don't work in Facelets.

Comment: Why is ForEachHandler included then? Because it already exists in JSTL anyway, no? I would ask the question if it implemented half of the classes required for running Servlets.. It does not include ANY of them, but includes some of JSTL, but that some is not even enough to work itself.. This is strange behavior and to me makes no sense..

Comment: JSTL's `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.*` is API, the `com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.*` is just an implementation of that API, suited for Facelets rather than JSP.

Comment: I added the interface LoopTagStatus and compiled it myself, included in the classpath of Tomcat and all seems fine.. I really find this behavior strange. I think this interface should be included in the JSF implementation. (copied from: http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl-api/1.2/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.java/?v=source)

Comment: The JSF implementation only provides the JSF API. It may provide an implementation of other APIs, but it should not provide another API. That's not JSF specific. That's just how it works with Java libraries in general. Java libraries may have dependencies on other libraries. Having duplicate API classes in runtime classpath is only recipe for disaster. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8081234

Comment: Sorry, just a small question: Where would be the JSTL implementation in such an application: http://www.tugay.biz/2015/06/sample-maven-java-web-application.html ? I do not have the JSF jars here. Does servlet-api or jsp-api which comes together with Tomcat implements jstl already?

Comment: Ah ok..From the wiki page: This is by the way the JSTL API bundled with Apache's JSTL implementation in a single JAR flavor. This is confusing! So if I import this dependency, I am having duplicate files, because JSF already implements jstl and this dependency also comes with the implementation.. I must find the API only dependency.

Comment: Ah ok, I think this is the API only dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/1.2.1? Interesting and confusing..

Comment: Apache's JSTL implementation is only for JSP. You indeed don't need it, using JSF on JSP is a nightmare ;)