# How to retrieve FacesContext with Java 17, Spring 6, Jakarta Server Faces 4.x and PrimeFaces 12?

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, jakarta-migration

I am trying to migrate my JSF + PrimeFaces (UI) + Spring application from Java 8 to Java 17, whilst also migrating Spring version to 6.
For this to work, there is a need to move from the javax libraries to jakarta libraries.
jsf-api and jsf-impl of com.sun.faces are removed. Keeping only org.glassfish:jakarta.faces.
Did add required libraries from different sources available on the internet.

The problem where I am stuck is that FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); was used in a @PostConstruct annotated method of a bean that is @ViewScoped and is used with @Named annotation.

I am getting the exception since facesContext is null, the object of facesContext is not getting initialised.

FacesConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facesconfig_4_0.xsd"
              version="4.0">



    <application>

        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>messages</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>

        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="6.0"
         xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd">

    <display-name>controlfwk</display-name>
    <description>controlfwk</description>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:spring-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
        <!--<param-value>${spring.profile}</param-value>-->
        <param-value>prod</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.abc.def.cfk.web.service.rest.RestService
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>smoothness</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>360</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <path>/</path>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I tried removing FacesContext as in commented, UI does come up with that but that's not a solution.

I added all Jakarta EE jars that were suggested in different forums but could not make any difference. Replaced ManagedBean with Named and ManagedProperty with Inject annotations.

I am expecting to get FacesContext object for something like:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map<String, String> parameterMap = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
```

This is just one example of I need FacesContext.

Note: Things did work with Java 8, PrimeFaces 6, JSF 2.2.8-02, Spring 4.x.

**Edit**:
As per the comment given by BalusC, I have removed jakarta.faces-api and added org.glassfish:jakarta.faces.

I am still not getting the FacesContext object. I followed everything mentioned in the duplicate link [How to properly install and configure JSF libraries via Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081234/how-to-properly-install-and-configure-jsf-libraries-via-maven) provided.

Comment: *"jsf-api and jsf-impl of com.sun.faces are removed and I am now using jakarta.faces-api of jakarta.faces"* You essentially upgraded API and removed impl. This is wrong. You need to upgrade them both. Use `org.glassfish:jakarta.faces` to have a single dependency containing both api and impl. See abovelinked duplicate for in-depth explanation.

Comment: I have provided an edit to the question and also removed jakarta.faces-api.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @lubrum no, I did not. Turns out, the more I read about it and asked around, people mentioned it is not possible to achieve something like this. The reason mentioned was that for this combination, JSF annotations would not work well with Spring and vice versa. We had to halt the migration.

Comment: In this link I have a module called 'livraria-spring-3' with spring boot 3.x, Primefaces 13.x, and Java 17, see if this can help you (https://github.com/Lubrum/livraria), the readme is in Portuguese but can be easily translated.