# Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet

Tags: java, maven, jsf, tomcat

I am building a PoC for using JSF and am using `Tomcat 7.0.59` as my server. My `pom.xml` looks like :

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Java.Net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I looked up for the error and found out that it is caused due to the `javaee-api` but looks like even after adding that particular dependency the issue isn't resolving. There is a different thread but it is on different servers like glassfish, jboss and doesn't seem to be working on my case.

EDIT : After suggestions from Samuel and Tiny, I have reached to this pom.xml :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And maven dependency tree looks like :

```
 com.Sourabh:SourabhTest:war:0.1
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- javax.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] \- com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.1.7:compile
```

Comment: You are likely having multiple `FacesServlet`s on the class-path from more than one JAR file containing JSF APIs. You are running on Apache Tomcat. Why is `javaee-api` dependency needed? Tomcat is not a Java EE compliant container. Paste the tile in the Google search box. A match will be found within no time.

Comment: I found [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8081384/1391249) of the best matches, by the way.

Comment: @Tiny: okay so i removed javaee-api since tomcat is non-compliant to Java EE. but i am still facing issue. I have servlet 3.0, tomcat 7.0.59 and jsf 2.1 i think all three are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet-api must be flagged with `<scope>provided</scope>`, as the jar in provided by tomcat. If you don't you might encounter class loader issues.

To ensure that you don't have several time the same dependency (through transitive dep.) you can run `mvn dependency:tree` or go in the dependency hierarchy plugin in eclipse

Comment: I was previously using 3.0.1 version for servlet api but since tomcat 7 provides servlet 3.0 I used `<version>3.0.1</version>` and `<scope>provided</scope>` but maven is branding it as missing artifact after i updated the project.

Comment: Can you update your answer with your pom, and the complete error message ?

Comment: 3.0 doesn't seem to be available on the maven central repo : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api

Comment: I think you can safely use 3.0.1 at compile time, ans 3.0 provided by tomcat at runtime

Comment: Exactly my thought... and its not working with 3.0.1.

Comment: I am using 2.3.1 as my maven compiler plugin although I don't it matters.

Comment: I undertood that you tried 3.0.1 without scope provided, and 3.0 with scope provided. Did you try 3.0.1 with scope provided ?

Comment: Yes I did that as well.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is just the pom.xml dependencies or could it be that the my build method that is flawed?

Comment: You can run maven dependency:tree or go in the "dependency hierarchy" tab in eclipse to see if you have this dependency imported as a transitivve dependency (by jsf for instance)

Comment: I don't think there is any transitive dependencies involved. For once I even removed servlet-api as I don't really require it right now in my project. Tomcat's servlet-api is suffice for runtime.

Comment: The same. No change. I had put in servlet jsp because the maven-archetype was selected to be webapp and I guess i brings in an index.jsp so I had to facilitate HTTPServlet for jsp. But I don't have business requirements of such. So I removed them both. But the error message is the same.

Comment: There must be several confilcting jars. Can you please post the result of mvn dependency:tree ? Is there any jsf jar in your tomcat shared libs ?

Comment: Done :) No I haven't configured tomcat shared lib.

Comment: Ok so it seems a specific jsf issue. I see a couple of possible fixes here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807549/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-o If this doesn't you will have to ask balusc :)