# JBoss REST API won't start up, Related to CDI?

Tags: java, rest, jboss, containers, cdi

I am translating my Monolith Webservice into a Microservice that lives in a container running out of docker (running 1.12.3 at the moment).  The application server is: jboss-eap7:2.2.0-1.6.9.

I initially created a barebones REST api that had little in the way of code in it and just a hello world.
However after adding some CDI components into my application I always get this exception...

```
21:40:57,240 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."wackyEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."wacky.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."wackyEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."wacky.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "wacky.war" of deployment "wackyEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"
```

There is more:

```
    21:40:57,245 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "wackyEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) - failure description: {
user-api_1  |     "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"wackyEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"wacky.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"wackyEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"wacky.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"upload-api-talon.war\" of deployment \"wackyEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\"
```

How do I package my application so that I enable CDI?

right now my application is package as

--wackyEAR
  --wackyWAR
  --lib
    --wackyEJB1 (CDI EJB app)
    --META-INF
        --beans.xml
    --wackyEJB2 . (CDI EJB app)
      META-INF
        --beans.xml

I am running out of ideas?

Here are the full logs:

```
23:13:03,533 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."app.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."app.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "app.war" of deployment "app.ear"

        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)

        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)

        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Failed to link javax/faces/webapp/FacetTag (Module "deployment.appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.app.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/webapp/FacetTag

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)

        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)

        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)

        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:605)

        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)

        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)

        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)

        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)

        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)

        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)

        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)

        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)

        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)

        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)

        ... 5 more



23:13:03,538 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) - failure description: {

    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"app.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"app.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"upload-api-talon.war\" of deployment \"upload-api-talonEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\"

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Failed to link javax/faces/webapp/FacetTag (Module \"deployment.appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.app.war:main\" from Service Module Loader): Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/webapp/FacetTag"},

    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".beanmanager]"]

}

23:13:03,559 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear" (runtime-name : "appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear")

23:13:03,560 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report

WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:

      service jboss.deployment.unit."appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear".weld.weldClassIntrospector]

WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."app.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."app.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "app.war" of deployment "appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"
```

Comment: That's what I said... :) What did you want clarified?

Comment: During deployment within wildfly, the cause may be due to wrong sub-module configuration or your deployment CDI configuration. Unless you put better logs, we really cannot help.

Comment: I updated by posting the full set of logs that I receive.  I was hoping this was a common issue.  Looks like it is not.  Which makes me think that I am not setting up my project correctly

Comment: See if this [Java lang classformaterror absent code attribute in method that is not native o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807549/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-o) or any of BalusC's links in the comments help you out.

Comment: Basically, you have a JAR in your WAR file that includes one of the spec JARs.  Can you include the contents of your WAR file?

Comment: So I realized that I didn't have the EJB's listed in the application.xml.  I added them, and my library directory is pointed to the right directory as well
<module><ejb>app.jar</ejb></module>
<module><ejb>app2.jar</ejb></module>
<library-directory>lib</library-directory>
I am getting an WFLYEE0031: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR [\""], module file app.jar not found
So different error, progress!